# PathGraphics not working in real-time or runtime generated

Tags: entity, cesiumjs

Have simple app using Cesium. I have basic entity with ellipse graphics, moving around, and I need to display its path, using PathGraphics, but it doesn't seem to work for me.
Here's code sample.

```js
const position = new SampledPositionProperty();
const start = [16.096912, 40.4100289];

const startTime = JulianDate.now();

position.addSample(startTime, Cartesian3.fromDegrees(...start));

const diff = 0.0002;
const [x, y] = start;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  const d = JulianDate.addSeconds(startTime, i + 1, new JulianDate());
  const newPos = [x + diff * (i + 1), y + diff * (i + 1)];

  position.addSample(d, Cartesian3.fromDegrees(...newPos));
}

app.entities.add({
  ellipse: {
    semiMinorAxis: 10,
    semiMajorAxis: 10,
    material: Color.RED,
  },
  path: {
    resolution: 1,
    width: 5,
    material: Color.YELLOW,
  },
  position,
});
```

But when I launch it all I see is moving ellipse, but no path is drawn. Everywhere I searched they say you just have to have position as SampledProperty and it will work, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

In this case, as you can see, I generate data beforehand, but I also tried adding it in runtime - same result. The only working examples i was able to find where using czml - but it doesn't fit my needs - it will be real-time app.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by digging through Cesium Sandcastle - you have to set `availability` property to entity with time range you want path to be shown. Would be cool if it was covered in documentation at least in some way.